# Added UIBarButtonItem covers UINavigationController back button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I added a `UIBarButtonItem` to `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` when my app runs on RTL device configuration and `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` when LTR device configuration.
In both configuration added `UIBarButtonItem` covers the back button which is the defualt button.

Here is my code:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(150), height: CGFloat(20)))
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
    label.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha:0.5)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    label.textColor = UIColor(hexaValue: ConsColors.albums)
    label.text = "Just text"
    label.sizeToFit()
    if UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirection.rightToLeft{
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: label)
    }else{
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: label)
    }
```

I even tried with a normal system `UIBarButtonItem`.
Also tried to set `UINavigationcontroller` semantic Content Attribute force RightToLeft or LefttoRight which doesn't work.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToleft
```

I use Swift 3, Xcode 8.1 and an iPad Air 2 with it's OS verion being 9.3.2
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Will appreciate the help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this property below

```
self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
```

This will make sure custom buttons are added after the back button

**Update:**

As per my understanding, your requirement is to have default back button and a custom button in opposite side. The below condition is not required for that

```
    if UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirection.rightToLeft{
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: label)
    }else{
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: label)
    }
```

Replace that with

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: label)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it isn't covering the back button now, though what i wanted to achieve is back button on one side and another button/view on the other side and not both button on the same side. which happens to me.

Comment: When my device configured LTR it works , the back button is on the left side and the second button is on the right side. Though when device is configured RTL back button and second button are beside each other on the right side. strange behavior. And as i have searched there isn't self.navigationItem.rightItemsSupplementBackButton :(

Comment: Thank you, you are right no need for the if statement. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like by explicitly setting the right bar button item, you are overwriting the stock back button. Fortunately there is a built-in way you can have multiple left bar button items, and it is even simpler than you might think. Rather than setting `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`, just set `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems` instead! Here is an example:

```
let backButton = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
let newButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: label)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [backButton, newButton]
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried that and it keeps covering the back button , though even if it didn't what i wanted to achieve is back button on one side and another button/view on the other side and not both button on the same side.